# How to add all packages into jar without plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have add this package in my project because my project is a commandline project

```
 implementation 'info.picocli:picocli:4.6.3'
```

When I run project, it throws ClassNotFoundError, like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: picocli/CommandLine
at com.lenovo.cosly.cli.Run.main(Run.java:10)
```

I use the plugin named shadow.jar to solve the problem at the last moment, like this

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.1.0'
}
```

How can I solve that without this plugin?

Comment: Why you don't want to use shadow jar? Do you have problems with it?

Comment: I only want to use native application , if the third-party have some problem , it will cost much time to fix them

Comment: The same argument could be used for picocli. Why use it if its third party? Why use Gradle at all instead of javac? It's third party too ;) See, just because something is from a third party doesn't mean it should be avoided. You don't have to reinvent the wheel every time. It's all about reliability. Some exotic library that someone wrote 5 years ago should be avoided, of course, but popular libraries/plugins that are actively maintained make your life **a lot** easier. Even more, they are usually more reliable than self-written code

Comment: So just stick with shadow jar if you have no problems with it and beeing third-party is your *only* reason

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to create a "fat jar" using only gradle. For example you could modify the jar task:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.baeldung.fatjar.Application"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

See this tutorial for more infromation: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar

Comment: now i write like this , it not completely solve problem  -- archive contains more than 65535 entries.

Comment: If I add zip64=true , it can be packaged successfully. But when I run this project , it 
was wrong by ClassNotFoundException again.

Comment: You need to exactly know what you are doing to make it work properly. This is a reason why shadow jar plugin exist, to make your life easier

Comment: So , if I want to write a program which can add all packages into a jar when it build in a short time , is it impossible？

Comment: The problem seems to be solved . I exclude the RSA files which is under the directory 'META-INF' when it build , and  it can work . @jhueg